integral of matrix exponential times some function
I am fairly new to this community, so apology if the question is not asked in the good manner.
Is there any robust way to calculate $$\int_0^\infty e^{Ax} \lambda e^{-\lambda x}  dx $$
where A is a square matrix with eigenvalues are all smaller or equal to 0.
I know that $$e^{Ax}=Pe^{Dx}P^{-1} $$ and the integral can become $$P\int_0^\infty e^{Dx} \lambda e^{-\lambda x}  dx P^{-1}= P
\begin{bmatrix}
\int_0^\infty \lambda e^{(d_1-\lambda)x}dx & 0 & \cdots &0 \\
0 & \int_0^\infty \lambda e^{(d_2-\lambda)x}dx & \cdots &0 \\
0 & 0 & \ddots & 0 \\
0 & \cdots & \cdots & \int_0^\infty \lambda e^{(d_n-\lambda)x}dx
\end{bmatrix}P^{-1}
$$
$$
=P \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\lambda}{d_1-\lambda} e^{(d_1-\lambda)x}|_0^\infty & 0 & \cdots &0 \\
0 & \frac{\lambda}{d_1-\lambda} e^{(d_2-\lambda)x}|_0^\infty & \cdots &0 \\
0 & 0 & \ddots & 0 \\
0 & \cdots & \cdots & \frac{\lambda}{d_1-\lambda} e^{(d_n-\lambda)x}|_0^\infty
\end{bmatrix}P^{-1}
$$
As all eigenvalues are less than or equal to 0, the resulting function is:
$$
=P \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{-\lambda}{d_1-\lambda} & 0 & \cdots &0 \\
0 & \frac{-\lambda}{d_1-\lambda} & \cdots &0 \\
0 & 0 & \ddots & 0 \\
0 & \cdots & \cdots & \frac{-\lambda}{d_1-\lambda}
\end{bmatrix}P^{-1}
$$
This seems mathematically okay, but when I compute this, the $P^{-1}$ is numerical unstable for large matrix A.
Is there any way to get the integral without explicitly finding $P^{-1}$, or maybe aother approach to find the integral?
Thank you

this can be integrated analytically

@user619894 can you elaborate how to integrate analytically? I know that $e^{Ax}$ can be expanded by using taylor series, do you mean integrate the expanded series of  $ \frac{(Ax)^i}{i!} \lambda e^{-\lambda x}$? In doing so I would get a sum of series of matrix times the integral of $x^{i} e^{-\lambda x} $?

I meant (see my answer) that $\int dx e^{Ax}e^{-\lambda x} = \int dx e^{-x(\lambda I - A)}$ and the matrix can be treated as a scalar since all powers of $(\lambda I - A)$ commute.

If $A = PDP^{-1}$ then $(A-\lambda I)^{-1} =P \text{ diag}\left(\frac{1}{d_1 - \lambda_1}, \dots, \frac{1}{d_n -\lambda_n}\right)P^{-1}$. So the solution to your integral is just $-\lambda(A-\lambda I)^{-1}$.

Thank you. This is exactly what I want

I tried to expand the matrix exponential by taylor series and got something like $I+\frac{A}{\lambda}+\frac{A^2}{\lambda^2}+\frac{A^{n}}{\lambda^{n}}$. It is like a geometric series, if all eigenvalues' absolute value is smaller than 1, then the resulting is $(I-frac{A}{\lambda})^{-1}, which is somewhat similar to what you suggested. But the caveat by expanding is that my matrix sometime has eigenvalues' absolute value larger than 1, and the geometric series may not converge. Yours is much more succinct and does not have any of those restriction.

Note that @LeeFisher 's result is true even if $A$ is non diagnosable:
$\int dx e^{Ax}e^{-\lambda x} = \int dx e^{-x(\lambda I - A)}$.
So, as long as $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} e^{-x(\lambda I - A)} = 0$ and $(\lambda I - A)$ is invertible, we can treat this as a scalar integral to get
$$\int dx e^{-x(\lambda I - A)}=(\lambda I - A)^{-1}$$
In more detail, note that $${d\over dx} e^{-x(\lambda I - A)}=-(\lambda I-A)e^{-x(\lambda I - A)} $$ so $$ \int dx e^{-x(\lambda I - A)} = \int dx(A-\lambda I)^{-1}{d\over dx} e^{-x(\lambda I - A)}$$ and we can use integration by parts.
